# Почему в Java не разрешено создавать локальные интерфейсы?

Tags: java, классы, интерфейс

Вот странно то, что локальные интерфейсы создавать нельзя, но вот абстрактные локальные классы создавать можно.

Вопрос: Почему интерфейсы запрещено создавать локально, в то время как абстрактные классы разрешено?

Просто очень интересно знать и понять причину такой странности. Другое дело, если и абстрактные классы были бы запрещены создавать локально, тогда было бы легче понять по крайней мере на уровне "предположения"

Внимание: Если данный вопрос вдруг оказался дубликатом, тогда просто вставьте ссылку в комментах, без негативных голосов. Если содержание ссылки дает исчерпывающий ответ, тогда я свой вопрос удалю.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под термином "локальный"?

Comment: Объявленный в теле метода.

Comment: Из самого названия "интерфейс" очевидно его назначение, подразумевающее бессмысленность видимости в пределах одного метода.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Я тоже так подумал, но тогда вопрос. А абстрактный класс почему разрешен? Вроде тоже бессмысленно или нет?

Comment: Потому что разрешены не именно абстрактные классы, а вообще классы. Если бы локальные классы нельзя было объявлять, то нельзя было бы в том числе и анонимные. А без анонимных классов нельзя было бы  использовать слушатели событий, например.

Comment: Ок. Тогда завершающий вопрос: А есть ли какая то польза от абстрактных локальных классов?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Статические локальные классы запрещены точно так же, как и локальные интерфейсы.

Comment: @РостиславКрасный спасибо за эту тонкость.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516375/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-local-interface-in-java) ответить можно так: это явно не разрешено в спецификации языка в виду определений локальных классов и интерфейсов. И, можно предположить, разработчики языка не видели причин это разрешать.

Локальный класс - это всегда внутренний класс [[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)], а интерфейсы, если не объявлены в файле - неявно статические и, засим, не могут считаться внутренними классами [[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)]

В итоге тело метода объявлено [так](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7):

```
MethodBody:
    Block 
    ;
```

а `Block` объявлен [так](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2):

```
Block:
    { BlockStatementsopt }

BlockStatements:
    BlockStatement
    BlockStatements BlockStatement

BlockStatement:
    LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
    ClassDeclaration
    Statement
```

Как можно увидеть из приведённого выше - в методе можно объявлять локальные переменные, классы или использовать выражения. Интерфейсы - нельзя.

Наверное, такое решение принято по причине того, что разработчики языка не видели таких проблем, которые могла бы такая возможность решить.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что интерфейс обязан быть статическим и неявно всегда объявляется таковым, но в Java ничто локальное не может быть статическим. По этой же причине локальный класс так же не может быть статическим. Более того, внутри локальных и вообще любых внутренних нестатических классов так же запрещены статические блоки, методы и поля, кроме констант, то есть кроме полей `static final`.

В языке C можно создавать статические локальные переменные и там это означает, что значение такой переменной сохраняется до следующего вызова функции, то есть память, используемая для такой переменной, не освобождается, вплоть до завершения работы программы. В Java решили не идти по этому пути.